# Como Sumar Arreglo

Tags: jquery

como podría meter los valores de "Price" a un arreglo para poderlo sumar?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  vtexjs.checkout.getOrderForm().done(function(orderForm) {
      console.log(orderForm);
      var items = orderForm.items;
      
      $.each(items, function(i, item) {
        var seller = item.seller;                      
        console.log(seller);   
        if(seller == "1"){
          var price = item.price;
          console.log(price);
          
          var rest = [];
          
          /*let suma = rest.reduce((a, b) => {
              // Sumar número actual
              a += parseInt(b) || 0;
              return a;
          }, 0);
          // Comprobar
          console.log(suma);*/
          
        }
      });         
      
  });
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: meter los valores?, te refieres al metodo [push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)?, si no es asi, podrías especificar mas.

Comment: si, me refiero a en una nueva variable guardar los valores de Price en un arreglo, para sumarlos

Comment: ```rest.push(price)```, pero tu array rest tendrias que declararlo fuera del each, ya que sino se estaría creando en cada item recorrido

Comment: Sigue saliendo por separado, actualice la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El array se debe declarar fuera del `each`, entonces al iterar tus items se deberían ir guardando en el array `rest` con el metodo `.push`, entonces al salir del `each` es cuando ya se termino de llenar el array, es ahi cuando deberías llamar la función que los suma, te dejo un ejemplo ejecutable para apreciar el resultado:

```js
 var rest = [];
 var seller = "1"
$.each([50,50,10,10,20], function(i, item) {
         
        console.log(item);
          rest.push(item)
        
      });  
   
   
let suma = rest.reduce((a, b) => {
              // Sumar número actual
              a += parseInt(b) || 0;
              return a;
          }, 0);
          // Comprobar
          console.log("suma total",suma);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Entonces tu codigo quedaria algo como:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  vtexjs.checkout.getOrderForm().done(function(orderForm) {
      console.log(orderForm);
      var items = orderForm.items;
       var rest = [];
      $.each(items, function(i, item) {
        var seller = item.seller;                      
        console.log(seller);   
        if(seller == "1"){
          var price = item.price;
          console.log(price);
          
          rest.push(price); // en cada iteracion, se mete el valor de price en el array
        }
      });         
      
      let suma = rest.reduce((a, b) => {
              // Sumar número actual
              a += parseInt(b) || 0;
              return a;
          }, 0);
          // Comprobar
          console.log(suma);
  });
});
```